# Problema com CSS no JSF&Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, cdi

Projeto -- JSF CDI Mysql //Não estou usando Maven

Boa Tarde pessoal, minha questão é a seguinte: Gostaria de ao invés de utilizar style="....."; no código xhtml, para deixar mais elegante o código, fazer uso do css.

por exemplo, quero ao invés de :

```
<p:fieldset style="background-color: #9ECADE;">
```

fazer uso de uma classe no css para então atribuir o estilo. Criei então um diretório em WebContent - resources - css - style.css dentro do css então fiz uma pequena edição:

```
.barra-navegacao{
    background-color: #9ECADE;
}
```

e dentro do meu template, fico assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous"
        rel="stylesheet" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style2.css" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div id="cabecalho" align="center">
        <p:graphicImage library="img" name="logo01.png" />
        <h1 align="center">
            <p:fieldset>
                <ui:insert name="titulo" />
            </p:fieldset>
        </h1>

    </div>

    <div>

        <ui:insert name="conteudo" />

    </div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

porem, o problema é que a edição não funciona, **e quando funciona, é como se ficasse salvo em algum lugar o css, e quando eu edito, não atualiza a edição** no css. Alguém poderia me ajudar pfvr ??

Aliás, gostaria tmb de saber, como altero um componente do Primefaces, por exemplo: cor, tamanho e etc por classes css. Estou com a doc baixada, e pesquisando nela, mas ta difícil kk''

Comment: Para alterar componentes do Primefaces, eu costumo sobrescrever o css do componente. Se você usa algum tema da comunidade, pode utilizar o ThemeRoller para alterar todo o tema: https://jqueryui.com/themeroller/. Ele gera pra você um arquivo css já com os estilos que você sobrescreveu, mas talvez ainda necessite de alguns ajustes.

Answer (score 1):

Vamos lá, você pode usar classes css sim, basta ao invés de usar o `style`, use o `styleClass`. Ex:

```
styleClass="barra-navegacao"
```

Para alterar css de um componente, veja na documentação qual a calasse e sobrescreva a mesma.

https://www.primefaces.org/documentation/

Comment: Então, estou utilizando o styleClass , porem ao editar pela primeira vez, ok, funciona legal. Porem se eu mudo por exemplo, a cor. Ele não carrega a cor e permanece com a anterior...